# phoenix hbase not connecting remotely

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have two cloudera VM and on both i've configured phoenix and it is working fine as long as it is localhost.

When i'm trying to connect hbase from one VM from phoenix of another VM, i'm using this command

```
$ ./sqlline.sh xxx.xx.xx.xx:2181
```

The connection is successful, but phoenix is still referencing the local HBASE and not the remote HBASE. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: "xxx.xx.xx.xx:2181" - Are you sure you are using the Zookeeper IP of the correct cluster?

Comment: Yes, its a single cluster.

Comment: You said "Two cloudera VM" are these 2 diff clusters? If yes they cannot share the zookeeper right?

Comment: I was trying for remote connection.. Cant i use phoenix driver to connect externally?

Comment: You should be able to connect to an external HBase cluster too. But that cluster has to have Phoenix jars installed in them.

Comment: Try to set zookeeper root node like xxx.xx.xx.xx:2181:/hbase (may it's called differently, hbase-unsecure, hbase-secure)